# SQL Error [42703]: "ILQASRC" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.31.10

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

Stored procedure not getting executed on DB2 luw via Dbeaver Application.

I created a stored procedure under my schema 'ILQASRC' which exists in a DB2 luw database. The code of the procedure is as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ilqasrc.create_n_columns(IN num_of_cols INTEGER,IN schema_name VARCHAR(20),IN typ VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN 
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE create_sql VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE alter_sql VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE table_name  VARCHAR(20);

SET table_name=schema_name||'.COLUMNS_'||num_of_cols||'_'||typ;

SET create_sql='CREATE TABLE '||table_name||'(PK INTEGER NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(PK))';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_sql;

SET i=0;
WHILE i < num_of_cols-1 
DO
IF MOD(i,8)=0 THEN
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' INTEGER';
ELSEIF MOD(i,8)=1 THEN
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' BIGINT';
ELSEIF MOD(i,8)=2 THEN
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' DECIMAL(9,5)';
ELSEIF MOD(i,8)=3 THEN
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' CHAR(10)';
ELSEIF MOD(i,8)=4 THEN 
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' VARCHAR(10)';
ELSEIF MOD(i,8)=5 THEN
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' DATE';
ELSEIF MOD(i,8)=6 THEN
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' TIME';
ELSE 
SET alter_sql='ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD COLUMN COL'||i||' TIMESTAMP(6)';
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE alter_sql;
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;  
END@
```

To execute the above procedure I executed the below statement:

```
CALL ILQASRC.CREATE_N_COLUMNS(1012, ILQASRC, varchar);
```

But I get the below error upon execution :

```
SQL Error [42703]: "ILQASRC" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.31.10
SQL Error [42703]: "ILQASRC" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.31.10
  "ILQASRC" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.31.10
  "ILQASRC" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.31.10
    An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "ILQASRC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.31.10
    An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "ILQASRC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.31.10
  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "ILQASRC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.31.10
  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "ILQASRC".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.31.10
```

Comment: I removed tag db2-400, the text of message SQL0206 isn't the one that is shown for this software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the procedure but in the call syntax, you just have to put values for varchar parametersbetween quotes like

```
CALL ILQASRC.CREATE_N_COLUMNS(1012, 'ILQASRC', 'varchar');
```